# Tutorial on reacts.org trying to set up a new project

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

i want to create a new project locally following the instruction on: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-option-2-local-development-environment ---> where it says run --> npx create-react-app my app

i tried doing that but i get Error code E404

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put like `my-app` not `my app` because `my` and `app` will be two seperate argument.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```